gdb: print global variables of a chosen shared library only
I need to find all global variables by certain name-pattern in gdb. So I can do:
info var MyPattern

But there are lots of them in the dump.
Is there a way to print only those from a chosen shared library (by specifying one of those shown by info dll or by specifying a range of addresses maybe)?

I see in title global variables and I feel chills. You can list variables by: info variables <library_name>

@MarekR, Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately it does not work for me. I get All variables matching regular expression <library_name>:

I don't think you can do better than calling the shell in gdb, which is a bit more convenient than working in two terminals. E.g.say this is the shared
library of interest.
$ cat foobar.c
int foo_abc = 42;
char foo_x = 'c';
static const char *barhw = "hello world";
float barf = 1.23;

char const *hw(void)
{
    return barhw;
}

$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.c

And this is a program that links with it:
$ cat main.c
int puts(char const *);
char const *hw(void);

int main(void)
{
    puts(hw());
    return 0;
}

$ gcc main.c -L. -lfoobar -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'

I'll debug into it and just break when libfoobar.so is loaded, but you
can break where you like.
$ gdb a.out
...[cut]...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in a.out)
(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 1
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out 
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/libfoobar.so
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) shell ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcfafc9000)
    libfoobar.so => /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/./libfoobar.so (0x000071e33b6d2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000071e33b400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000071e33b6de000)
    

Now I know the path to libfoobar.so.
...
(gdb) shell readelf --syms --wide /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/./libfoobar.so | egrep OBJECT.*\(foo\|bar\).* | sort -k8 -u
     8: 0000000000004010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 barf
    10: 0000000000004018     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   20 barhw
     5: 0000000000004008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_abc
     6: 000000000000400c     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_x
     

Those are the global (including static) variables in libfoobar.so that match (foo\|bar\).*
...
(gdb) shell readelf --syms --wide /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/./libfoobar.so | egrep OBJECT.*GLOBAL.*\(foo\|bar\).* | sort -k8 -u
     8: 0000000000004010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 barf
     5: 0000000000004008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_abc
     6: 000000000000400c     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_x

Those are the global extern variables in libfoobar.so that match (foo\|bar\).*
(gdb) shell readelf --dyn-syms --wide /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/./libfoobar.so | egrep OBJECT.*\(foo\|bar\).*
     5: 0000000000004008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_abc
     6: 000000000000400c     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 foo_x
     8: 0000000000004010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 barf
     

Those are the global dynamically visible variables in libfoobar.so that match (foo\|bar\).*
...
(gdb) p (char const *)barhw
$1 = 0x7ffff7fba000 "hello world"
...[whatever]...

If you're working with C++ code, add --demangle to the readelf options.
